# In c++ how to check a pointer lies within a range?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

Intuitively to check whecker pointer `p` lies in [`a`,`b`) one will do

```
a<=p && p<b
```

However, comparing pointers from two arrays results in unspecified behavior and thus we cannot safely say `p` is in [`a`,`b`) from this comparison.

Is there any way one can check for this with certainty?

(It would be better if it can be done for `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`, but I don't think it's feasible.)

Comment: Reinterpret the pointer as `uintptr_t` and use that to compare the addresses, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170927-00/?p=97095 for some more in-depth info

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you checking the range of a pointer? Why are you using raw pointers at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "lies within a range"? Point to an element of the same array as `a` and `b` point to?

Comment: Not entirely serious: you can use a loop... `for(auto x = a; x < b; ++x) if(x == p) return true; return false;`

Comment: @UnholySheep even though `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold any pointer, the mapping of pointers to integers still might be strange and unsuitable to range checking.

Comment: There is no "language-lawyer" way to do it.  **C++ runs on systems where every approach suggested here will fail.**  On specific platforms, you may have success with converting to integer as @UnholySheep suggested.

Comment: Note: one such system where the check is complicated is x86 real mode, where pointers use segmented addressing.  Note: it's also complicated (read: damn near impossible from user-mode) for any system using virtual address translation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial solution. You can leverage the fact that the comparison would invoke unspecified behavior, and the fact that a core-constant-expression can't perform this operation:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool check(T *p, T *a, T *b)
{
    return a <= p and p < b;
}
```

Now this function can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int arr_2[5];
    constexpr bool b1 = check(arr + 1, arr, arr + 3);    // ok
    constexpr bool b2 = check(arr_2 + 1, arr, arr + 3);  // error
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Padnz).

This obviously works only if the pointer values are known at compile time. At run-time, there is no efficient way of doing this check.

Comment: _the comparison would invoke undefined behavior_ It would invoke unspecified behavior

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, ok. Is the compiler diagnosing unspecified behavior then? Is that even required?

Comment: [An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions: a relational or equality operator where the result is unspecified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.21)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Aah, ok, so the technique is ok, but wording was wrong. Edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for pointers is to use the comparison objects defined in `<functional>`, like `less`/`less_equal`, etc.

From [§20.8.5/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/comparisons#8) of the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) standard<sup>1</sup>:

> For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, **even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not.**

So the solution for pointers would be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool check(T *p, T *a, T *b)
{
    return std::less_equal<T*>{}(a,p) && std::less<T*>{}(p,b);
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rv7rfr) using pointers.

---

There is no such strict guarantee for iterators; however this can be worked around in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), since it provides [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) which can convert pointable objects to pointers. Note, however, that the behavior of doing this for the purpose of comparisons is only really well defined for contiguous iterators.

Since we know that `std::vector` iterators cover a contiguous range, we can use this to retrieve the underlying pointer (**note:** *not* dereference it, as this would be **undefined behavior** for the past-the-end pointer).

So for a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, a solution might look like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool check(const std::vector<T>::const_iterator p, std;:vector<T>::const_iterator a, std::vector<T>::const_iterator b)
{
    // Delegate to the pointer check version defined above, for brevity
    return check(std::to_address(p), std::to_address(a), std::to_address(b));
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/no5jd8) using iterators.

---

<sup>1</sup> This same note exists all the way back to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) under [§23.14.7/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/comparisons#2), with similar wording.

Comment: `check(p, a, b) == true`, for `a` and `b` pointing to elements of the same array, doesn't guarantee that `p` points to an element between those ones.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The linked sections of the standard guarantee that the functional objects will have a **total ordering** comparison. I'm not sure what part of that was unclear, but even in the scenario you describe a total order is well-defined. Additionally, it appears that OP is asking about `p` being from a different array (which would otherwise be **unspecified**), not that `a` and `b` are different arrays. This is also how other answers appear to be interpreting this question

Comment: It is unclear what OP wants, but if OP wants to check whether `p` points to an element of the same array as `a` and `b` do, `std::less` won't help.

Comment: `std::less` is *required* to follow the ordering imposed by `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` for pointers as part of their total ordering. As a result, it's _required_ that if `p` is in `[a,b)` that `std::less` continue to work. A corollary of that is that if `p` is _not_ in `[a,b)`, that the result must continue to be totally ordered -- and thus must still continue to work. Even a case of `a` and `b` being different arrays will still produce a totally-ordered result -- it just won't be a well-defined result since it relies on implementation specifics

Comment: I know that `std::less` gives total order. I wanted to say that `check(p, a, b)` may hypothetically be true even when `a<=p && p<b` is false.

Comment: @Human-Compiler, from my other reading of similar questions, the obligation of total ordering does not ensure that intuitive result for the problem. I assume that `a`, and `b` in the problem are of the same array, and thus the question is to check whether some pointer refers to an address within a contiguous memory segment. The partial ordering of <, must be preserved, but the total ordering is any, it does not have to be the one you have implicitly chosen. I could choose to have `p`, which is not inside `a` and `b` in memory to be within in for the sake of my ordering.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if vector iterator is between two other vector iterators.

Then you may use [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to compute distance between vector.begin and a, p and b and then simply compare itegers you get from *distance* return value.

Comment: This won't work. If `p` is not between `a` and `b`, the behavior of `std::distance(a, p)` is undefined. There's nothing meaningful that you can do with it.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I suggested computing distance from .begin() - is this undefined?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you got `a` from. Algorithms apply to sequences; if `p` is not in the sequence defined by `[a,b)` you cannot call `std::distance(a, p);`.

Answer (score -2):

`std::distance(first, last)` from C++17 can be used for both, but result is undefined if `last` is unreachable from `first` (e.g. different range or invalid iterator)

Comment: So this can give you the distance between `a` and `b`. But if `p` is not in the `[a;b)` array, then calculating the distance from `p` to either is undefined behavior. In that case, how can this be used to determine if `p` is a member of the `[a;b)` array?

Comment: @Frodyne if you can guarantee that `a` and `b` are belonging to same array and results are consistent with it, it does belong to range. If you can't guarantee that `[a, b)` is legal range, you can't guarantee correctness of result, some implementations may yield exception in that case

Comment: My interpretation of OP's question is: `T arr[27]; a=begin(arr); b=end(arr);` and then the question is; for some random pointer `T* p;` is `p` pointing at a member of `arr` (that is into the `[a;b)` range).  Under this interpretation `distance(a,b)` is of course valid, but `distance(a,p)` would only be defined if `p` indeed is pointing into `arr`. Am I wrong, misunderstanding something, or are you reading OP's question differently?

Comment: @Frodyne technically if (a,p) is positive and (p,b) is positive distance and their summ is equal to (a,b), p SHOULD be part of array. If we assume it isn't part of array, it would mean that there is some pointer q which got same distances as p, i.e. it is same pointer : `q = a + std::distance(a,p)`. By definition `q` is pointing to same object a `p`, which contradicts assumption. Note, C++ guarantees uniqueness of adresses. Second limitation ensures that p is not out of bound. Now, if a and b aren't bounds of same range, we don't have that guarantee.

Comment: @Frodyne The only edge case is when p was created from alternative member of union. Memory location or adresses may be shared, but that pointer needed to be laundered formally.